# Rails routes with the same block in resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have this routing:

```
resources :placements, only: :index do
    collection do
        put :update_all
        delete :destroy_all
    end
end
resources :designs, only: :index do
    collection do
        put :update_all
        delete :destroy_all
    end
end
# etc...
```

There are too much same code and it looks ugly. Is there any way to get something like that:

```
with_options only: :index, collection: { update_all: :put, destroy_all: :delete } do
    resources :placements
    resources :designs
end
```

Thanks in advance! :)

PS: This code looks good, but not working :(

Comment: routes file is just Ruby code, so you should be able to do it by defining a `with_options` function that makes the necessary arrangements. You'll need to handle the "resources" function calls when the block is yielded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 4 has [routing concerns](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) that you can use to do this:

```
concern :standard_routing do
  collection do
    put :update_all
    delete :destroy_all
  end
end

resources :placements, only: :index, concerns: :standard_routing
resources :designs,    only: :index, concerns: :standard_routing
```

That said, the routes DSL is just Ruby code, and the `do` blocks are...just blocks! So even without any special support, you could wrap this up into a nice easy generator, or reuse procs.

```
def standard_actions_for(*resources)
  Array(resources).each do |resource|
    self.resources resource, only: :index do
      collection do
        put :update_all
        delete :destroy_all
      end
    end
  end
end

standard_actions_for :placements, :designs
```

or:

```
standard_routing = Proc.new do
  collection do
    put :update_all
    delete :destroy_all
  end
end

resources :placements, only: index, &standard_routing
resources :designs,    only: index, &standard_routing
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that it is just DSL, but i try to find standard Rails tool. And you help me )